# ISCHANGED trigger in PB

Tags: formula, process-builder

There is some weird behavior going on with a fairly basic Process Builder setup.

There are 5 (working) nodes that only react on `Case Status` update and are set to be executed only when the specific changes are made to the record.

There is also `Status Date` field and idea is to trigger an action every time this date field is changed.

**By using a formula**, it does not react at all:

```
ISCHANGED([Case].Status_Date__c )
```

**By using conditions** and setting:

`Status_Date__c [Is Changed] [Boolean] [True]`

It works only if no other updates are done. Meaning if `Status Date` is updated at first, the action will trigger correctly. If someone updates the `Case Subject` (this field is not used in the Process at all) and after that changes `Status Date` in a separate edit, then it no longer triggers the action.

What is the issue here?